# Need Facebook App ID from Page ID.

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like, facebook-javascript-sdk

is there any way to get facebook **APP ID** from facebook **Fane Page ID**?
I've facebook fan page id and now i want to get facebook AppId. please tell me if there is a way or it is possible??

Thanks

Comment: A Page itself has NO App ID... What exactly do you mean?

Comment: I mean I've facebook Fan Page Id and I want to get AppId using this PageId.

Comment: You cannot "get AppId using this PageId". Pages and Apps are only "connected" when Apps are used in Page Tabs.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to get an AppId from a fanpage because fanpages are not Apps, therefore they dont have App Ids.
Perhaps you are thinking of a Page Tab App, and still you can't get it's Id just by having the id of the page the App is in.

**Tip:** Explaining what you are trying to achieve might help people understand the problem you are having.